# setting date manually to date picker returns one date always

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, datepicker

I get my date from server not device date.but there is problem with changing date

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        datepicker2.datePickerMode = .date
        datepicker2.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")
        datepicker2.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
        datepicker2.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        datepicker2.date=self.minDate // this is a date var filled
        datepicker2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datepickerAction(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

each time I change the date prints just one date

```
func datepickerAction(_ sender: UIDatePicker){

     let date = self.datepicker2.date

let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day,.year], from: date)
let hour = components.month
let minute = components.day
    let yr=components.year
    print(hour,minute,yr) // prints one date always
}
```

this is the date I get from server :

```
func CurrentdateAndTime(){



        let url=URL(string: "\(address)date/getNewDate")


        var urlrequest=URLRequest(url: url!)

        print(url)

        var time:String=""


        urlrequest.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlrequest) { (data, response, error) in


            if let data=data {

                let json=String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                let b:Double=Double(json!)!

               // if !b.isZero{
                    self.setComperehensiveDate(longDate: b)
                    self.settime(longTime: b)
                    self.setDay(day: b)
                    self.setYear(year: b)
                    self.setmonth(month: b)
                    self.setHour(longTime: b)
                    self.setMin(longTime: b)
                    self.onComplete?("ok?")
              }


            }.resume()


    }



 func setComperehensiveDate(longDate:Double){

        let dbl = TimeInterval(longDate)

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dbl / 1000)

        //let formatter = DateFormatter()

        print("long",longDate,dbl)

//        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
 //       formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
  //      formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")
        //formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"
        //let a = formatter.string(from: date)


      // resultDate = formatter.date(from: a)

        resultDate = date
        print("aaa",resultDate)

    }
```

I get millisecond from server set on func that converts to date then I get it

and I get minDate data this way :

self.minDate=getcomperehensiveDate()

update : my problem is if user takes his device date to the past manually or future the picker shows the the past which I don't want this. I must show the current date thats why I'm setting date programatclly and facing this issue so what is your idea about this scenario ?

Comment: Could you add the code that sets the `datepicker2`'s date?

Comment: update my first post

Comment: Could you print `self.minDate`?

Comment: 2018-08-08 09:39:47 +0000

Answer (score 0):

`datepickerAction` is called after changing the value of `datepicker2` on a real device or the simulator.

The following should work normally:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    datepicker2.datePickerMode = .date
    datepicker2.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")
    datepicker2.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
    datepicker2.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    // The following line is setting the datepicker2.date to Tomorrow, because you haven't posted the code giving self.minDate
    datepicker.date = Date().addingTimeInterval(24 * 3600)
}

func datepickerAction(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let date = self.datepicker2.date
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day,.year], from: date)
    let month = components.month //This is the month component, not the hour like in your code
    let day = components.day //This is the day component, not the hour like in your code
    let yr = components.year
    print(day!,month!,yr!)
}
```

If you want the hour and minute components you'll just have to define `components` like so:

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .hour, .month, .day,.year], from: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```

Comment: @M0TRIX could you elaborate more? What's not working?

Comment: as same as it was. returns only one date

Comment: You mean, it prints always the same string? even when you change the date manually in the simulator/real device?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It would be helpful if you could post all the code related to `self.minDate`

Comment: cheek my first post again

Answer (score 0):

I can see issue with your line

```
let date = self.datepicker2.date
```

it must be getting the same date or something. I can see you are giving the same date

```
datepicker2.date=self.minDate (this is issue)
```

I just tried using

```
@IBAction func change(_ sender: Any) {

        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day,.year], from: datepicker.date)
        let hour = components.month
        let minute = components.day
        let yr=components.year
        print(hour,minute,yr)
    }
```

it's same picker working fine. 
please download the project from the link:

https://github.com/sanojKashyap/51799141_S

Comment: when I comment my setting date command it is working well but I need to set a date

Comment: you'r date is not changing its same, try having datepicker date.

Comment: my problem is if user takes his device date to the past manually or future the picker shows the the past which I don't want this. I must show the current date thats why I'm setting date programatclly and facing this issue so what is your idea about this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you set the UIDatePicker date in viewDidAppear.  viewDidAppear and viewWillApear are not reliable enough to be used to call one time setters, use viewDidLoad as this is guaranteed to only be called once.

I learned this the hard way and after putting a breakpoint  in the problematic date setter I traced it back to the fact it was set in the viewDidLayoutSubviews override.  Another no-no apparently which led me to your question.